# "if (var)" uses number conversion instead of boolean

Tags: c++, if-statement, types

Why if (var) ... uses number conversion instead of boolean ?
I have a class that implements both :

```
operator int() { ....}
operator bool() { ....}
```

but if I use :

```
if (my_class_var) ....;
```

then the `int` conversion is used instead of `boolean` ?!!?!

EDIT:
As versedmarald say it is correct. I found what was the differnce.. I'm in fact using :

```
operator int() { ....}
operator bool() const { ... }
```

Still mesmerized, why the difference ?
gcc version 4.6.2

Comment: Don't know the answer, but just for my curiosity: does it use bool if you force it by casting (e.g. `if ((bool)my_var)`)?

Comment: Are you sure? If what you're saying is really the case, it sounds like a compiler bug. Visual C++ uses the `operator bool()` conversion.

Comment: Atleast [gcc-4.3.4 uses bool operator overload](http://ideone.com/Ko3Vn). What compiler are you using?

Comment: GCC 4.7.1 uses the bool opeartor as well.

Comment: Looks like compiler bug. Also `if(!!my_class_var)` shall do the trick.

Comment: Are your operators intentionally non-const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't (using `g++` at least). My guess would be there is an error in your conversion operators.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    operator int() { return 1; }
};

class B {
public:
    operator int() { return 1; }
    operator bool() { return false; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    if (a)
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "false\n";

    if (b)
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "false\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
true
false
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer anything, this should actually be a comment.

Comment: @Als I disagree. "It doesn't." is most certainly a valid answer to the question: "Why does `if (var)` uses number conversion instead of boolean?".

Comment: @veredesmarald "It doesn't" can be a valid answer, "it doesn't on g++" isn't (IMO) unless the question is about g++. That said, it's useful and too large to fit in a comment, so for lack of a better option, no complaint from me :)

Comment: @hvd Fair enough, I guess "It shouldn't" is more accurate. Either way, if I have to guess between "the compiler is buggy" and "the code is buggy", I'm taking "code" every single time. :)

Comment: you are correct, if found what is the difference.. if you modify it like this : operator bool() const {return false;}, then it returns true , true

Answer (score 3):

If what you say is true, I believe your compiler is in violation of the Standard:

> (§6.4/4) The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). If that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. [...]

(To be clear, this is in the context of §6.4, which describes `if` and `switch` statements.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two `used-defined implicit conversion chains`.

First - `class -> bool -> no conversion`

Second - `class -> int -> bool`

n3337 4/2

> Note: expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other types in several contexts:
>
> — When used in the condition of an if statement or iteration statement (6.4, 6.5). The destination type
> is bool.

n3337 4/3

> The effect of either implicit conversion is the same as performing the
> declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.

Quotes means that really

```
if (class_var)
```

is

```
if (bool _ = class_var)
```

n3337 13.3.3/1

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
> F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
> standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
> entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
> the return type of F2 to the destination type. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
> A();
> operator int();
> operator double();
> } a;
> int i = a; // a.operator int() followed by no conversion
> //is better than a.operator double() followed by
> //a conversion to int
> float x = a; //ambiguous: both possibilities require conversions,
> //and neither is better than the other
> ```
>
> — end example

So, compiler should choose `operator bool`, since `class -> bool -> no standart conversion` is better than `class -> int -> standard conversion to bool`